# Java - loop in GUI repeats instead of counting iterations

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a Java quiz, which interprets data input by the user about one dimension of an array (questions) and verifies them against the second dimension (correct answers). After creating it in CLI, I have added jFrame capabilities, and left it with the intention of checking the way it works through the IDE console output (System.out.println) and adding the jFrame output later. However, the loop designed for answer checking does not function as intended.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Console input = System.console();
    Random r = new Random();
    int randq = r.nextInt(4);
    String answer;
    String[][] Qs = new String[4][2];

    Qs[0][0] = "A?";
    Qs[0][1] = "A";
    Qs[1][0] = "B?";
    Qs[1][1] = "B";
    Qs[2][0] = "C?";
    Qs[2][1] = "C";
    Qs[3][0] = "D?";
    Qs[3][1] = "D";

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 4;) {
        randq = r.nextInt(4);
        jLabel1.setText(Qs[randq][0]);
        add(jTextField1);
        answer = jTextField1.getText();
            if (answer.equals(Qs[randq][1])) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                jTextField1.setText("");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect, the answer was " + Qs[randq][1]);
                jTextField1.setText("");
            }
            counter = counter + 1;
    }
}
```

Entering "A" against "A?" outputs:

```
Correct!
Incorrect, the answer was A
Incorrect, the answer was D
Incorrect, the answer was D
```

The aim is for the program to repeat for the number of questions, but instead it repeats itself times the number of questions EVERYTIME it gets a question. Furthermore, for some reason, it does not interpret any of the answers after the first one, as you can see with "Incorrect, the answer was A".

I can't tell what's wrong just through reading line-by-line. Thank you in advance.

Comment: set `break` statement as you have found the correct answer.

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `break` out of your loop once the correct answer has been found.

```
if (answer.equals(Qs[randq][1])) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    jTextField1.setText("");
    break;
}
```

---

Also it is very strange that this line

```
counter = counter + 1;
```

is at the end of that loop.

Not sure if you wrote this but you could remove that line by making the loop as follows

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) {
    // Do work
}
```